# Windows 10 Bluetooth activation

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp

In my Windows 10 UWP app I activate bluetooth by executing the following code:

```
var result = await Radio.RequestAccessAsync();
if (result == RadioAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    var bluetooth = (await Radio.GetRadiosAsync()).FirstOrDefault(radio => radio.Kind == RadioKind.Bluetooth);
    if (bluetooth != null && bluetooth.State != RadioState.On)
        await bluetooth.SetStateAsync(RadioState.On);
}
```

This code works perfectly except on my laptop (Lenovo Yoga Pro 3) when my bluetooth is not activated on boot: the bluetooth variable is null (so I can't activate it). If I enable bluetooth and disable it, then it also works. On an another laptop it works.

So, there is a parameter in the bluetooth device or in the Windows 10 OS that enable this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you're not alone. I've tested it on Lenovo Yoga 1st and Macbook Pro 12'mid, both have the same issue. Looks like the Radio enumerations don't find bluetooth devices when it's disabled on boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good catch. However, it is not specific to Lenovo Yoga, I'm seeing it on other laptops as well.

So the problem is you're not enabling the "Bluetooth Support Service" on system startup.

You can go to Service Manager, find the "Bluetooth Support Service", double click it, and in the pop-up window, make sure you change the "Startup type" to "Automatic".

[image]

Good luck!